# Is there a demo that shows WCF versioning?

Tags: wcf, versioning

Is there a practical example or demo that walks you through creating a service and then breaking it because of improper versioning.  Most examples I see on the web just tell you what it is, but don't walk you through a demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dhananjay Kumar shows some code samples for data contract versioning on these blog posts:

- http://debugmode.net/2010/10/03/versioning-in-wcf-data-contract-part-1-adding-new-members/
- http://debugmode.net/2010/10/03/versioning-in-wcf-data-contract-part-2-missing-members/

There is also some guidance on MSDN with a bit of code about all around versioning in WCF:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff384251.aspx